# TinyMCE Jquery - No default buttons, themes, how do i specify default paths?

Tags: jquery, path, tinymce

This is driving me nuts!@#!@# I can load the tinyMce plugin for jquery just fine....but it looks for its own images/themes relative to the CURRENT URL.

ex.

tinymce tries to load http:/mysite/mycurrenturl/tiny_mce/whateverM
when tinymce is located in http:/mysite/js/tiny_mce

so for some reason i can not seem to find any documentation to specify a default path so tinyMce knows where it supposed to look!

Thanks if anyone knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think (its been a while since I've used tinyMCE) that its designed to be deployed in one location, so the location for themes is always assumed to be inside the tiny_mce directory. The [documentation on themes](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/theme) seems to back this theory up.

Comment: right..but its not looking in its own dir, its just adding its own /dir/ to the path of the page im looking at (acting as relative)

i need absolute in this case

Comment: Ahh.. well that is annoying. What version are you running? Also have you tried posting on the tinyMCE forums, I have used them in the past & got reasonable responses (including from the dev team)?

Answer (score 0):

ok i am a moron

i am using cake php and i was loading the tinymce from the "Vendors" path.
Ckaephp will rewrite the urls and it just gets screwy. I put it in my webroot/js/ and it worked out fine.
Thanks!